# How to get object with google.visualization lib?

Tags: google-visualization, google-sheets-api

I am trying to get the data from google spreadsheet with google.visualization. 
I am using this code and it works great, but I hope there is a way to get the same object with just google.visualization (same object but without d3.csvParse). I read the docs but cant find any suitable function (just an example with new google.visualization.DataView(convertedData) => view.getNumberOfRows() etc.)

```
var googleDataQuery = response.getDataTable().toJSON();
var convertedData = new google.visualization.DataTable(googleDataQuery, 0.5);
var data = d3.csvParse(google.visualization.dataTableToCsv(convertedData))
```

**UPD:** d3.csvParse returns an object like  [{name:"test1"}, {name:"test2"} .... ]
I think google.visualization can do this somehow so I can skip this part `d3.csvParse(google.visualization.dataTableToCsv(convertedData))`

Comment: exactly what does `d3.csvParse` return?

Comment: @WhiteHat the object like [{name:"test1"}, {name:"test2"} .... ] Like if I parse a csv file.

Comment: Not sure if that's the case, but shouldn't [getTableProperties](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_getTableProperties) return this information?

Comment: @Iamblichus I am getting null with this  var googleDataQuery = response.getDataTable().toJSON();
            var convertedData = new google.visualization.DataTable(googleDataQuery, 0.5);
            var view = new google.visualization.DataView(convertedData);
            console.log('view', view, view.getTableProperties());